# React-Admin: How do I hide the "Checkbox" with the Datagrid <row>?

Tags: material-ui, react-admin

Within my `App`, we have `permissions` like `ADD/DELETE` based on roles.

- `Admin` has all permissions to `add`, `delete`, `edit` the `records`
- `customers` don't have the `delete` permissions.

I therefore want to hide the `delete` **checkbox** within the `<Datagrid>` for customers.

```js
//RoleList.js

import React from "react";
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, SingleFieldList, ChipField, EditButton, DeleteButton, ReferenceArrayField, Loading } from "react-admin";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  chips: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light
  }
}));

const RoleList = ({ permissions, ...props }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  if (!permissions) return <Loading />;
  const permissionsList = permissions.split(",");

  return (
    <List {...props} title="roles">
      <Datagrid rowClick="show">
        <TextField source="name" />
        <ReferenceArrayField reference="permissions" source="permissions">
          <SingleFieldList>
            <ChipField source="name" className={classes.chips} />
          </SingleFieldList>
        </ReferenceArrayField>
        {permissionsList.includes("edit_roles") && <EditButton />}
        {permissionsList.includes("delete_roles") && <DeleteButton />}
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};

export default RoleList;
```

This is my component where I hide `edit` and `delete` button based on `permissions`, but the **checkbox** is still functional.
Am I missing anything from `react-admin`?

Comment: Kindly **add** to the code snippet, how you are using `permissions` to hide the `checkboxes`. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To hide the checkboxes:

```
<List
    {...props}
    bulkActionButtons={false}
>
...
</List>
```

Answer (score 5):

To hide those checkboxes in RA v4 or greater:

```
<Datagrid
    {...props}
    bulkActionButtons={false}
>
...
</Datagrid>
```

The *bulkActionButtons* prop was moved from List component to Datagrid component in RA v4.